# Align bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my website (team section) I have something like this 6x :

```
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/female-employee.png)">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The issue is that I don't know how to align the last 2 ones to the middle of the bag, like on the illustration below.

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks,
[image]

Comment: You can use the `col-md-offset-*` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [**bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/oTea5I7wZX): http://www.bootply.com/oTea5I7wZX

On the last row with [**offseting columns**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) :

```
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
          </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
          </div>
          </div>          
</div>
```

**Full HTML**

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
          </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-4">
        <div class="team-member">
          <div class="image" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/150x150')">
          </div>
          <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
          <p class="position">Sells</p>
        </div>
          </div>
          </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box for last row as below:

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class="team-member align-center">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/female-employee.png)">
      </div>
      <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
      <p class="position">Sells</p>
    </div>
    <div class="team-member align-center">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/female-employee.png)">
      </div>
      <p class="name">Jane Doe</p>
      <p class="position">Sells</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add the class `align-center` as below:

```
.align-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: I've reverted my downvote because you're essentially correct, but this is a bootstrap related question and a bootstrap related solution should be provided